# Como recorrer dos arrays y sustituir un elemento por otro del segundo array

Tags: javascript, array, poo

En Javascript tengo un array de 250 objetos como los dos que adjunto:

```
     const film = [
 {
      title: 'Dog Day Afternoon',
      year: 1975,
      director: 'Sidney Lumet',
      duration: '2h 5min',
      genre: ['Biography', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
      score: 8
    },
    {
      title: 'Dead Poets Society',
      year: 1989,
      director: 'Peter Weir',
      duration: '2h 8min',
      genre: ['Comedy', 'Drama'],
      score: 8
    }
  ];
```

y otro array de 250 items con el tiempo de la pelicula pasado a minutos en el mismo orden, en lugar de '2h 8min', `128`. la cuestión es que debo sustituir "duration:" con el nuevo formato por lo que el array film debería quedar así:

```
const film = [
 {
      title: 'Dog Day Afternoon',
      year: 1975,
      director: 'Sidney Lumet',
      duration: '125',
      genre: ['Biography', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
      score: 8
    },
    {
      title: 'Dead Poets Society',
      year: 1989,
      director: 'Peter Weir',
      duration: '128',
      genre: ['Comedy', 'Drama'],
      score: 8
    }
  ];
```

Se que debería recorrer los dos arrays y sustituir uno por otro pero no se como hacerlo. Si alguien puede ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Porque no haces un `for(let i=0; i<filmA.length; i++) { filmA[i].duration = filmB[i].duration }`. Suponiendo que filmA es el array que quieres cambiar y filmB el array que tiene las duraciones como numero

Comment: Genial, funciona!  no sabia que con un solo for se podian recorrer los dos arrays y cambiar un valor por otro. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando el `forEach`, quizá haya otra manera más óptima, pero estame sirivió a mi:

```js
const film = [
        {
             title: 'Dog Day Afternoon',
             year: 1975,
             director: 'Sidney Lumet',
             duration: '2h 5min',
             genre: ['Biography', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
             score: 8
           },
           {
             title: 'Dead Poets Society',
             year: 1989,
             director: 'Peter Weir',
             duration: '2h 8min',
             genre: ['Comedy', 'Drama'],
             score: 8
           }
         ];

         const film2 = [
            {
                 title: 'Dog Day Afternoon',
                 year: 1975,
                 director: 'Sidney Lumet',
                 duration: '125',
                 genre: ['Biography', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
                 score: 8
               },
               {
                 title: 'Dead Poets Society',
                 year: 1989,
                 director: 'Peter Weir',
                 duration: '128',
                 genre: ['Comedy', 'Drama'],
                 score: 8
               }
             ];
        
        let i=0; 
        film.forEach(elemento => elemento.duration = film2[i++].duration); 
        console.log(film);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!